# Graphs with Primary & Secondary Axes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create these quite often. I can export data from R into Excel and do it there, but I'd much prefer to do the whole thing with R code. If I have - as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(city = c("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Berlin", "Tokyo"),
                 pop  = c(8000000, 5000000, 2000000, 2500000, 15000000),
                 var_1 = c(1000, 1100, 1050, -200, 1200),
                 var_2 = c(900, 1050, 950, -400, 1000),
                 var_3 = c(1100, 1200, 1250, -100, 1300))

df$city <- df$city |> as.factor()
```

then I would like to produce a graph that looks something like this (done in Excel with the same data):

[image]

...and with the flexibility to manually alter the axis ranges (or some way to do it automatically) so that the blue bars stay below the lines (eg in this example I manually scaled the secondary axis to run from 0 to 30m in Excel).

I remember looking into this a few years ago and reading that `ggplot2` didn't allow for this. Is that still the case? Is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: The allowed way to do this is with `ggplot2::sec_axis`. You need to transform all values to one scale, and then provide the transform so that the second axis is labelled appropriately.

Comment: Thank you but I think I would struggle to do this - I find `ggplot2` very difficult to understand and this would be beyond my capability

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sec_axis` for this, and transform `pop` so that it is on the same scale as the `var` columns. In order to really advise the legend, we can also pivot it for easy plotting.

**Up front**, though, second axes can easily confound visual interpretation of plots, where the eyes naturally associated numbers on an axis with the wrong elements. We can mitigate this *a little* with color (assuming no color-blindness), though even then staunch graphistas (visualizationistas?) will oppose the use of a second axis. I'll create `cols` for the components, and make sure that the second axis is colored the same as the one column that is to be used on that side. (It becomes much more difficult when more than one element is used on the second axis ...)

First, we need to know an appropriate transform from `pop` to `var#` and back again.

```r
intcpt <- -600 # arbitrary, perhaps min(df[,3:5]) - 200
slope <- (max(df[,3:5])/2) / max(df$pop)
intcpt
# [1] -600
slope
# [1] 0.00004333333
```

Also, to mimic the order of cities across the bottom, we'll need to control the levels of the factors.

```r
df <- data.frame(city = c("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Berlin", "Tokyo"),
                 pop  = c(8000000, 5000000, 2000000, 2500000, 15000000),
                 var_1 = c(1000, 1100, 1050, -200, 1200),
                 var_2 = c(900, 1050, 950, -400, 1000),
                 var_3 = c(1100, 1200, 1250, -100, 1300))
df$city <- factor(df$city, levels = c("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Berlin", "Tokyo"))
```

From here, it's just some transformation and then plotting.

```r
cols <- c(var_1 = "orange", var_2 = "gray", var_3 = "yellow", Pop = "blue")
df |>
  transform(
    pop_height = pop * slope,
    pop_center = (pop * slope) / 2 + intcpt,
    pop = NULL
  ) |>
  reshape2::melt(c("city", "pop_center", "pop_height")) |>
  ggplot(aes(city, value, group = variable, color = variable, fill = variable)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_tile(aes(y = pop_center, height = pop_height, color = "Pop", fill = "Pop"),
            width = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = intcpt) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(intcpt-1, NA),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      name = "Population",
      ~ (. - intcpt) / slope,
      labels = scales::comma_format(),
      breaks = seq(0, 15e6, by = 5e6)
    )
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = NULL, values = cols) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = cols) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour = cols["Pop"]),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(colour = cols["Pop"]),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(colour = cols["Pop"])
  )
```

[image: ggplot2 with colored second axis]

Comment: Thank you. It works! Now I need to study the code to see if I can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really love that Excel look, you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(pop = pop/1.8e4) %>%
  mutate(across(var_1:var_3, ~.x - min(df[3:5]))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(city, value)) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(name == 'pop'), aes(fill = 'Population'),
           key_glyph = draw_key_path, width = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(name != 'pop'), 
            aes(color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(name != 'pop'), 
            aes(color = name, group = name)) +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, labels = ~.x + min(df[3:5]), limits = c(0, 1800),
                     breaks = 0:10 * 200,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x * 1.8e4, labels = scales::comma,
                                         name = NULL, 
                                         breaks = seq(0, 3e7, len = 7))) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = '#5b9bd5') +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('#ed7e33', '#a6a6a6', '#ffbf00')) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1, 
                             override.aes = list(color = '#5b9bd5',
                                                 linewidth = 2))) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.7, 0.8))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you certainly went to extra effort to mimic excel's plotting there, nice job!

Comment: Just a bit of fun @r2evans!

Comment: Thank you - it works nicely (as does the code in the other reply). I wish I understood `ggplot2` better. I'm pretty good at some R things, but this stuff I find completely bewildering. Some proper studying needed when I can find the time I think.